# How to expand AppInsights JavaScript SDK Error Logging to stringify

Tags: javascript, azure-application-insights

We have application insights hooked up to our front end angular app.  All of the errors logged in application insights are some form of `[object object]` or `[object ErrorNode]` or other object toString() representations.

I found this article https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/wiki/FAQ#im-seeing-a-lot-of-uncaught-object-object-errors-in-application-insights-in-azure-portal indicating that the JS SDK assumes there is a `message` property of the error and if not, then it will toString the error which typically results in a useless representation.  The article and linked articles indicate this as true, but do not provide any way to change this behavior or work around it.  We would prefer to JSON.stringify the error instead of toString of the error or be allowed to specify a formatter that can take an unknown error type and expand it as desired.  There is even an issues that's been open for a while here https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/issues/363.

We are considering adding another window.onerror callback that looks for these types of errors and sends a trace to app insights with the custom expansion of the error node.  However, that would not be associated to the original request and would just be an adjacent error.  We need to handle both dependency failures and non-dependency failures that are throwing errors without a `message` property.

Comment: Can you add the relevant code for this question?

Comment: What would be relevant code here?  We installed app insights and the way it is logging dependencies exceptions is not useful in our case.  We would like to override it and i'm asking how to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to disable the automatic tracking of exceptions (see `aiConfig.disableExceptionTracking`), and do your own tracking instead.  The code for how the default hookups occur is in the GitHub repo in the [_onerror method](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/72d2cc63c82141d84849e19450f4c53cbcc21dec/ApplicationInsights/src/JavaScriptSDK/ApplicationInsights.ts#L385) from what I can tell.

better yet, you could fix the issue in the [ApplicationInsights-js GitHub repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-js), and you could actually contribute the changes back to the sdk so everyone could benefit?

but the best place to post this would be to the GitHub repo for the app insights javascript sdk:

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-js/issues

Comment: I believe this issues is already tracked here https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/issues/363.  updating question to include this link.  If I do find a way to fix this, I will definitely contribute it back.